# How to get bounding box for model instances in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have create a Model (a box) and 100 instances of it, moved around in the world. They get rendered where they are expected to.

I'm now trying to implement ray picking but I have found that all 100 instances return the same bounding box of the original model. Why isn't the actual bounding box calculated for each instance?

Creating model and instances:

```
public static void createModel() {
   ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
   modelBuilder.begin();
   MeshPartBuilder tileBuilder;
   tileBuilder = modelBuilder.part("top", GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
   tileBuilder.rect(-0.45f, 0.1f, 0.45f,   0.45f, 0.1f, 0.45f,    0.45f, 0.1f, -0.45f,  -0.45f, 0.1f, -0.45f,  0f, 1f, 0f);
   tileBuilder = modelBuilder.part("bottom", GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
   tileBuilder.rect(-0.45f, 0f, -0.45f,    0.45f, 0f, -0.45f,     0.45f, 0f, 0.45f,     
...
   modelTile = modelBuilder.end();
}

public void createModelInstance(com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager assetManager) {
  Texture texTile = assetManager.get("textures/" + textureFile, Texture.class);
  Material mat = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texTile));
  modelInstance = new ModelInstance(modelTile); 
  modelInstance.nodes.get(0).parts.get(0).material.set(mat);
}
```

Moving the model instance:

```
public void setCoordinates(boolean animate, float x, float y, float z) {
  modelInstance.transform.setToTranslation(x,y,z);
  modelInstance.calculateTransforms();
}
```

Ray picking attempt:

```
public boolean pickTile(int x, int y) {
  cam.update();
  Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(x, y);
  BoundingBox bb = new BoundingBox();
  for (int i=0;i<gameData.tiles.length;i++) {
    Log.i("ltower", "checking " + i);
    gameData.tiles[i].getModelInstance().calculateBoundingBox(bb);
Log.i("ltower", "BB: " + bb.getCenter().x + "," + bb.getCenter().y + "," + bb.getCenter().z);
    if (Intersector.intersectRayBoundsFast(ray, bb)) {
      gameData.tiles[i].select();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Log:

```
01-05 05:27:18.934: I/ltower(2175): checking 0
01-05 05:27:18.984: I/ltower(2175): BB: 0.0,0.05,0.0
01-05 05:27:19.024: I/ltower(2175): checking 1
01-05 05:27:19.024: I/ltower(2175): BB: 0.0,0.05,0.0
01-05 05:27:19.044: I/ltower(2175): checking 2
01-05 05:27:19.064: I/ltower(2175): BB: 0.0,0.05,0.0
01-05 05:27:19.064: I/ltower(2175): checking 3
01-05 05:27:19.064: I/ltower(2175): BB: 0.0,0.05,0.0
01-05 05:27:19.064: I/ltower(2175): checking 4
01-05 05:27:19.064: I/ltower(2175): BB: 0.0,0.05,0.0
01-05 05:27:19.064: I/ltower(2175): checking 5
01-05 05:27:19.104: I/ltower(2175): BB: 0.0,0.05,0.0
01-05 05:27:19.104: I/ltower(2175): checking 6
01-05 05:27:19.104: I/ltower(2175): BB: 0.0,0.05,0.0 
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you just create several *instances* of the *same* `Model`, they also have the same `BoundingBox`. The bounding box will be just a bounding box around the vertices of the model's local coordinate system.

That means that you need use [BoundingBox.mul()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/collision/BoundingBox.html#mul%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4%29) to apply the model instance's position, scale and rotation to the bounding box.

Comment: Thanks, `bb = gameData.tiles[i].getModelInstance().calculateBoundingBox(bb).mul(gameData.tiles[i].getModelInstance().transform);` worked. Not sure I understood the concepts verywell then, when calling Modelinstance.calculateBoundingBox() I would logically expect to get the bounding box of the instance, not the model.